# I need to force time to char, so that the deployment looks cleaner

Tags: postgresql

First problem is that I have this output if I run the code in pgAdmin3:

[image: this is what I want]

But when deployed I get this:

[image: this is too long for my form]

Also can I replace negative time with text like this:

```
CASE WHEN TRUNC(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ((CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 
          AND wo.RESOLVEDTIME= 0 
     THEN DATE_TRUNC('second', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     ELSE CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 
          THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESOLVEDTIME / 1000) 
          ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESPONDEDTIME / 1000) 
     END 
END) - (TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.CREATEDTIME / 1000) 
     + (((sla.fr_duebydays * 1440) 
     +  (sla.fr_duebyhours * 60) 
     + sla.fr_duebyminutes) * interval '1 minute'))))/60) <0

        THEN **'overdue'**
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL, and it is unreadable. Maybe show the whole code. Rather than posting pgAdmin screenshots, show the output with `psql`.

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing timestamps as `text`?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out both of my problems. The first one (the one with time-stamp formatting problems) had to do with the fact that I was interpreting PostgreSQL query in another application (JasperSoft) in this case.

The workaround was to_char the whole expression. Like this:

```
TO_CHAR 
    (

    AGE( CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 AND wo.RESOLVEDTIME= 0 
            THEN DATE_TRUNC('second', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    ELSE      CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 
            THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESOLVEDTIME / 1000) 
    ELSE      TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESPONDEDTIME / 1000)


    END END ,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.CREATEDTIME / 1000) + (((sla.fr_duebydays * 1440) +  (sla.fr_duebyhours * 60) + sla.fr_duebyminutes) * interval '1 minute') 

        ), 'DD HH24:MI')
```

The other problem I had was with some negative time-stamp values that I would get from my query. The solution there was that once the expression was to_char, I included the whole thing into a "case" expression.

Like this:

```
CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME <= 0 -- this case gets read of the negative values in the table

    THEN

    TO_CHAR 
    (

    AGE( CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 AND wo.RESOLVEDTIME= 0 
            THEN DATE_TRUNC('second', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    ELSE      CASE WHEN wo.RESPONDEDTIME= 0 
            THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESOLVEDTIME / 1000) 
    ELSE      TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.RESPONDEDTIME / 1000)


    END END ,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(wo.CREATEDTIME / 1000) + (((sla.fr_duebydays * 1440) +  (sla.fr_duebyhours * 60) + sla.fr_duebyminutes) * interval '1 minute') 

        ), 'DD HH24:MI')
ELSE 'on time' END

    AS "Response SLA Violation"
```